# Wrap several functions inside SetTimeout

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Consider

```
onClick={() => {funcOne(); prop.funcTwo();}}
```

I want to wrap these functions inside setTimeout function, which is imported to a component from another file

```
   delay (...func) {
       return setTimeout(() => func, 1000);

    }
```

But I get an Error in console:

*Expected `onClick` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `number` type.*

How do I can wrap it properly?

PS: my example is uses React with Hooks

Comment: how are you using delay function

Comment: @ Shubham Khatri it just `delay`s execution for `n` milliseconds

Comment: If I correctly understand you want the two functions to be executed after a delay  on onClick event.

Comment: Yes, you are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the implementation of delay function so that it returns a function instead of timerId

```
  delay (func, delay) {
      return () => setTimeout(func, delay);
  }
```

and then use it like below

```
onClick={delay(() => {funcOne(); prop.funcTwo();}, 1000)}
```

Comment: What if I have other arguments to pass, beside the functions?

Comment: You can pass arguments to delay function, just make sure that the first argument is a function

Comment: Shubham Khatri, Thank you